# 画面内でマウスにより押された座標を表示するには

Tags: java

swingを用いて画面を生成した後、マウスイベント処理を用いてマウスにより押された座標を表示させる。そのためにMouseListenerインターフェースとaddMouseListener()を用いて実現することができるというところまでは理解したけれどもその先がチュートリアル等を参照しても進むことができないです。

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.*;
/*
画面を生成し、画面内でマウスが押されたらその座標が表示されるプログラム
*/
public class Mevent extends JFrame implements MouseListener{

    int x=0;
    int y=0;//マウス座標記録用変数
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGUI();
            Mevent m =new Mevent();
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("window");
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Mevent(){
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        Point point =e.getPoint();
        x=point.x;
        y=point.y;
        System.out.println("x:"+x+"y:"+y);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

寝て起きて数時間考えたら自己解決いたしました。以下、ソースコード

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.*;
/*
画面を生成し、画面内でマウスが押されたらその座標が表示されるプログラム
*/
public class Mevent extends JFrame implements MouseListener{

    int x=0;
    int y=0;//マウス座標記録用変数

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Mevent m =new Mevent();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("window");
            frame.setSize(300,300);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.addMouseListener(m);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        Point point =e.getPoint();
        x=point.x;
        y=point.y;
        System.out.println("x:"+x+"y:"+y);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

動いているので特に問題はないのですが少し修正すると以下のようになります。
元コードでは Mevent が JFrame を継承しているため別途 JFrame のインスタンスを作成する必要がありません。Mevent 自身が JFrame の機能をすべて持っているので以下のようにすればウィンドウが表示されます。

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.*;
/*
* 画面を生成し、画面内でマウスが押されたらその座標が表示されるプログラム
* */
public class Mevent extends JFrame implements MouseListener{

  int x=0;
  int y=0;//マウス座標記録用変数

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
      Mevent frame = new Mevent();
      frame.setVisible(true);
    });
  }

  public Mevent(){
    super("window");
    setSize(300,300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addMouseListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    Point point =e.getPoint();
    x=point.x;
    y=point.y;
    System.out.println("x:"+x+", y:"+y);
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
  @Override
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
}
```

あるいは「JFrameの機能」と「マウスイベントを表示する機能」を独立させたいならば Mevent は JFrame を継承する必要がありません。